# How to get param.value in action class

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, struts2

I am getting the values from previous page as

```xml
<param name="value1">${param.value1}</param> 
<param name="value2">${param.value2}/param>
```

Now on submit of this page how do I get the values in the backend (action or controller)? I tried this to get the values in my action class

```java
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
String startDate = request.getParameter("value1");
String endDate = request.getParameter("value2");
```

Here `value1`, `value2` are of `Date` types. I am getting the values as `null` in the request.

**EDIT:**

This is how I am getting the values

```jsp
<s:hidden name="value1" value="%{#parameters['value1']}"></s:hidden>
<s:hidden name="value2" value="%{#parameters['value2']}"></s:hidden>
```

Comment: You send them in a form or the URL, save way as any other request that wants to access parameters.

Comment: How did you check that values are null?

Comment: @RomanC i have a struts action called on popup form .

Comment: @DaveNewton i want to get the values in my action class.

Comment: Do you submit this parameters with the form?

Comment: yes i have a s:submit on popup form.

Comment: I'm not asking you about it, please read carefully and follow me.

Comment: We know that's what you want. Are the values represented in the form? We can't actually see your screen. If they're just in paragraph tags, clearly they won't be submitted.

Comment: i think these parameters will be available on submit of form, or i am wrong , i have updated my question how i am getting the values in my action class

Comment: Yes, you are wrong-the form submit is a new request. If the parameters aren't in the *form submission URL* or sent as form values, why would they be in a *new* request?

Comment: you can't use `param` tag without other tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting the values as `null` in the request

You didn't get parameters because you are looking them from the servlet request via [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) or form request body encoded data, but **you didn't pass that query string or encoded data to the request**.

When you submit the form you probably used [hidden](http://struts.apache.org/docs/hidden.html) fields as parameter names. This values retrieved by the [`params` interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/docs/parameters-interceptor.html) via `request.getParameterMap()`.

You can [reference](http://struts.apache.org/docs/interceptor-configuration.html) `params` interceptor that will do the work for you by setting those values to the action attributes. It's also included in the `defaultStack` if you don't want to override the action config.

Comment: hey Roman i am new to front end technologies. after passing the parameters as <param name="value1">${param.value1}</param> <param name="value2">${param.value2}</param> and at action using HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest(); String startDate = request.getParameter("value1"); String endDate = request.getParameter("value2");     i am still getting null values. please help on this.

Comment: You don't understand, you are calling a wrong method in that case you shouldn't do that.

Comment: execute method of  struts is called by default and i am not getting values there , i am not able to figure out what i am doing wrong..

Comment: where do you pass parameters?

Comment: are you getting parameters as `null` or as `"null"`?

Comment: it is coming as  null.

Comment: if you not submitting the form then you can't, the action should be mapped to the url.

Comment: edit you question add code, make clear the question, what you don't understand, what is not working and what did you try to make it work.

Comment: this is how i got the values  <s:hidden name="value1" value="%{#parameters['value1']}"></s:hidden>
     <s:hidden name="value2" value="%{#parameters['value2']}"></s:hidden>

Comment: @curious Please update the question and add this code and action code to the question. Did you solve it?